# Neural Network Weights in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

How do you apply weights in OpenCV 3 with the C++ ml.hpp library? I'm aware previously with the CvANN_MLP objects weights could be applied as follows:

```
mlp.train(trainData, trainClasses, weights);
```

However since CvANN_MLP has been depreciated, I can't seem to find documentation on how to apply predefined weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.

```
Ptr<TrainData> MLPdata = TrainData::create(trainingData, ROW_SAMPLE, trainingClasses, noArray(), noArray(), weights);
mlp->train(MLPdata);
```

Check out this [document](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d32/classcv_1_1ml_1_1TrainData.html#a5e0c052f9aadce1f75cddbdbbf9c4f4d) for more.

Comment: 1+ for telling how you figure it out. Some people just say: Yay! which is not very useful.